# libusb read: Double CR (0xD) put in buffer when single CR is in input

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, usb, libusb

I am using libusb bulk transfer to read a file that has multiple carriage returns throughout the file.  Every time it reads 0xd, it puts two 0xd characters in the receive buffer.  Using Visual Studio C++ with Windows 10 OS.  Has anyone else seen this or have an idea  of how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  I was trying to use traditional C or C++ methods to write out my data.  My input file had characters that these methods couldn't handle. I changed my output file to handle binary data and it solved the problem:

outFile.open(fileName, ios::out | ios::binary);